# A hard problem on conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

$U_{1}, U_{2}$ obeys a bivariate normal distribution with zero mean, variance $1$ and covariance $\rho$. How can we get $ E(U_{1}\mid U_{1}>U_{2}) $?  The hint is that we can use the fact that $U_{1}\mid U_{2} $ obeys $N(\rho U_{2},(1-\rho^2))$ and $P(U_{1}>U_{2})=1/2$. And for ease of notation, can use $Z$ obeys standard normal distribution. 
The answer is $2\rho E[Z \Phi(- ((1-\rho)^{1/2} /(1+\rho)^{1/2})Z )] +2(1-\rho)^{1/2}E[Z\Phi(((1+\rho)^{1/2} /(1-\rho)^{1/2})Z)] $. But how can we get this?

Comment: I guess that you missed to say that they are zero mean. And the $i$ subindexes are irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, thanks I corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint  Let $X=U_1$ $Y=U_2$ Then
 $$P(X|X>Y) = \frac{P(Y<X|X)\,  P(X)}{P(X>Y)}=\frac{\Phi \left( \frac{X-\rho X}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2} }\right) \phi(X)}{1/2} $$

where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the standard normal density, and $\Phi(\cdot)$ the distribution function.

The expectation of $X|X>Y$  is $\int X f(X) dX$ where $f(X)$, the pdf, is given above. That is

$$E(X|X>Y) = 2 \int X \, \Phi \left( \frac{X-\rho X}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2} }\right) \phi(X) dX$$

which, given that $\phi(X)$ is itself a pdf (that of a standard gaussian, say $Z$), (think of $\Phi$ as an arbitrary function) is

$$ 2 \, E \left[ Z \Phi \left(\frac{Z-\rho Z}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2} }\right) \right] = 2 \, E \left[ Z \, \Phi\left(  \sqrt{\frac{1-\rho }{1+\rho}\, } Z \right)\right] $$

Comment: Sorry, but I still have trouble solving it. Could you write the expression for the expectation? What kind of pdf should I use? I am confused....

Comment: Somebody should probably mention that expressions such as $P(X\mid X\gt Y)$ have no rigorous definition.

Comment: @Did Would you say so much? It's a pdf, conditioned on a well defined (joint) event. The notation is quite sloppy, but, as a density,  it could be written slightly better as $P(X=x|X>Y)$, or, better, use distributions $P(X \le x|X>Y)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the notation $P(Y<X|X)$ (used just afterwards) **is** well defined, but as a random variable... One should also object to the notation $\int Xf(X)dX$ since, if $X$ is a random variable, then what is $dX$? Ad lib.

Comment: By the way, the very last RHS is $$\frac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{1-\rho}.$$