# conditional expectation under bivariate normal

Tags: probability

When $X$, $Y$ are bivariate normal, how can we calculate the conditional expectation $E(X\mid X>Y)$? A more concrete setting of this general problem can be referred [A hard problem on conditional expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417182/a-hard-problem-on-conditional-expectation).

Comment: What the expression for the expectation takes? I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: It would be very helpful if someone could have a look at the specific question as I linked.

Comment: Relevant post on CV:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139072/distribution-of-the-maximum-of-two-correlated-normal-variables.

Answer (score 1):

If $(X,Y)$ is normal centered, there exists some nonnegative $(\sigma,\tau,\varrho)$ and $(U,V)$ i.i.d. standard normal such that $X-Y=\sigma U$ and $X=\tau U+\varrho V$. Thus,
$$
E(X\mid X\gt Y)=\tau E(U\mid U\gt0)+\varrho E(V\mid U\gt0)=\frac{2\tau}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$
To identify $\tau$, note that $\sigma^2=E((X-Y)^2)$ and $\sigma\tau=E((X(X-Y))$ hence $\tau$ can be deduced from the covariance matrix of $(X,Y)$.

The noncentered case is messier. There exists some nonnegative $(\sigma,\tau,\varrho)$, some $(a,b)$ and some $(U,V)$ i.i.d. standard normal such that $X-Y=\sigma U-a$ and $X=\tau U+\varrho V+b$. Thus,
$$
E(X\mid X\gt Y)=\tau E(U\mid U\gt a)+\varrho E(V\mid U\gt a)+b=\frac{\mathrm e^{-a^2/2}\tau}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1-\Phi(a))}+b.
$$
The values of the parameters $\tau$, $a$ and $b$ are identified thanks to the identities $\sigma^2=\mathrm{var}(X-Y)$, $\sigma\tau=\mathrm{cov}(X,X-Y)$, $b=E(X)$ and $a=E(Y)-E(X)$,.

Comment: I don't understand the second =sign on the first expression, that is if you look for >0)=.

Comment: what does "normal centered" mean?

Comment: @jacob The value $2\tau/\sqrt{2\pi}$ stems from the fact that $E(U; U\gt0)=1/\sqrt{2\pi}$, $P(U\gt0)=1/2$ and $E(V\mid U\gt0)=E(V)=0$. // Normal = Gaussian. Normal centered = normal and with expectation zero.